# I am sending a data with ajax. How can I reset the data sending process?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

**When I select an account that has purchased a product, I bring up an option showing which product it is, but if we select an account that has purchased another product, this option comes for the second time.**

my script code

```
$("select.account").on('change', function() {

    var accId = $(this).children("option:selected").val();
    
    console.log(accId);

    $.ajax({

        type: 'POST',
        url: 'netting/order-ajax.php',
        data: {
            'accId': accId
        },
        success: function(data) {
            
            if (data != "FALSE") {
                $('#accform').after(data);
                
            } else {
                $('#productform').hide();
            } 
        }
    })
})
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rFgO.png)

my order-ajax.php

```
if (isset($_POST['accId'])) {

$sql = $db->qSql("SELECT * FROM sales INNER JOIN account ON sales.accId = account.accId INNER JOIN product ON sales.productId = product.productId WHERE sales.accId = '{$_POST['accId']}'");

if ($sql->rowCount() > 0) { ?>

    <div id="productform" class="form-group">
        <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Ürün & Hizmet</label>
        <select class="form-control account" required name="accId">
            <option value="">Ürün & Hizmet seçiniz...</option>
            <?php
            $sql = $db->read("product", [
                "columnsName" => "productId",
                "columnsSort" => "DESC"
            ]);
            while ($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {   ?>
                <option value="<?= $row['productId'] ?>"><?= $row['productTitle'] ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
        </select>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.after(data)` keeps adding more content at the end of your form.

Instead, create a specific div or something into which you want to place this content, and use `.html(data)` to write into it. This will then overwrite the content each time you run it, instead of appending it to what was added previously.

References:

- https://api.jquery.com/after/
- https://api.jquery.com/html/